# AngularJS: ui-router Redirect view on success & refresh scope with new contents

Tags: angularjs, viewstate, single-page-application

I am migrating from ng-view to ui-view.

In my controller, upon successful create / update / delete, I would like to redirect to an index view with the newly updated / created / deleted data.

I currently do this using `$state.go`.

```
app.controller('AdminSupplierCreateController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Supplier', 
    function ($scope, $state, Supplier) {
        $scope.h1 = "Register a new Supplier";

        $scope.store = function()
        {
            Supplier.post($scope.supplier)
                .then(
                    function() {
                        console.log("Successfully Created Supplier");
                        $state.go('admin.supplier');
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        console.log("Error with status code: " + response.status);
                    }
                );
        };
}]);
```

The problem is that when the $state is changed, the scope is not updated. It appears as though the original `admin.supplier` scope data is not being refreshed.

I have tried refreshing the `ui-view` with `$state.reload()` before setting the scope in `AdminSupplierIndexController`.

```
app.controller('AdminSupplierIndexController', ['$scope', '$state', 'suppliers', 
    function ($scope, $state, suppliers) {
        $state.reload();
        $scope.suppliers = suppliers;
}]);
```

Doing this makes the get request to `api/v1/suppliers`, however it doesn't actually show the updated scope unless I either hit the refresh button on the browser or manually navigate to a different state, then navigate back again.

```
$stateProvider
    ...
    .state('admin.supplier', {
        url : "/supplier",
        templateUrl : 'templates/admin/supplier/index.html',
        controller: "AdminSupplierIndexController",
        resolve: {
            suppliers: ['Supplier', function(Supplier) {
                return Supplier.getList();
            }]
        }
    })
    .state('admin.supplier.create', {
        url : "/create",
        templateUrl : 'templates/admin/supplier/create.html',
        controller: "AdminSupplierCreateController"
    })
```

Solution:

```
app.controller('AdminSupplierCreateController', ['$scope', '$state', 'Supplier', 
    function ($scope, $state, Supplier) {
        $scope.h1 = "Register a new Supplier";

        $scope.store = function() {
            Supplier.post($scope.supplier)
                .then(
                    function() {
                        console.log("Successfully Created Supplier");

                                            // Force Reload on changing state
                                            $state.go('admin.supplier', {}, {reload: true});
                    },
                    function(response) {
                        console.log("Error with status code: ", response.status);
                    }
                );
        };
}]);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens because you move to parent state which is already created. You would have to signal to ui-router that you do want to reload it.

I think you might be looking for the `reload` option of `$state.go()`. Refer to the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state).

Also, a sort of a workaround might be to move the "index" state to a sibling state of edit. admin.supplier.index or so. Then it would be destroyed as you transition to admin.supplier.edit and recreated when you transition back and no additional options are necessary.

Also as a side note I guess it would be considered good practice to use `$state.go` instead of `$location` whenever possible.

Comment: Many thanks. This was solved using: `$state.go('admin.supplier', {}, {reload: true});` in the success callback of `Supplier.post`

Comment: This really helped and works exactly as I was expecting it to.